# Finding phrases in sentences

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to work on NLTK. I need to find out phrases in the sentences. Is there any common grammar or pattern available to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean by "phrase"? "Hey, how are you?" - is it 1 phrase or 2?

Comment: You are overcomplicating things for the assignment. You can split the string by spaces and search for one or multiple length phrases that way.

Comment: Sounds like you might want a [dependency parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar). Try the demo of the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) and look under the `Parse` and `Typed dependencies` sections.